# Google PubSub "Deadline Exceeded" with C# on premises

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Having an issue with identifying optimal settings for on-premises GCP PubSub Publisher client. Start getting "Deadline Exceeded" within hours of start sending data, with variation of "Stream removed" and "Connect Failed".

Metrics are not very extensive, and logging ByteCount and ElementCount from Publisher's GetCurrentFlowState() doesn't bring much information.

So far following setting works better (still "deadline exceeded"):

```
    private async Task Init()
    {
        _topicName = new TopicName(ProjectId, TopicId);
        var pubApiSets = PublisherServiceApiSettings.GetDefault();
        pubApiSets.PublishSettings = CreateRetryCallSettings(10);
        _pub = await PublisherClient.CreateAsync(
            new TopicName(ProjectId, TopicId),
            settings: new PublisherClient.Settings()
            {
              BatchingSettings = new BatchingSettings(
              elementCountThreshold: 1000, 
              delayThreshold: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), 
              byteCountThreshold: 256000)
            },
            clientCreationSettings: new PublisherClient.ClientCreationSettings(

                publisherServiceApiSettings: pubApiSets)
        );
        logger.Trace("client initialized");
    }

    private CallSettings CreateRetryCallSettings(int tryCount)
    {
        var retryBackoff = new BackoffSettings(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000), 2);
        var timeoutBackoff = new BackoffSettings(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(60000), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300000), 1.2);
        return CallSettings.FromCallTiming(CallTiming.FromRetry(new RetrySettings(retryBackoff, timeoutBackoff, Expiration.None,
            (RpcException e) => e.Status.StatusCode != StatusCode.AlreadyExists && --tryCount > 0,
            RetrySettings.RandomJitter)));
    }
```

Any advise how choose optimal settings?
Is there way to retrieve more detailed metrics for the Publisher client?

Comment: What percentage of your publish attempts are failing with deadline exceeded? Avoiding them 100% of the time won't really be possible. But the number of them should still be relatively low.

Comment: It deals OK with time to time failure to deliver. Until within 6 to 12 hours gets 100% of messages end up with Deadline Exceeded or others.

Comment: Could you provide a version of the client, stacktrace of the error and what you noticed before the error (like prolong period of idleness) so to provide some context for an investigation? You can take a look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors) for some strategies to work around the error. In case you are using API version 0.14.x you can refer to [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/2619) and upgrade your API version to try again.